# Will flask auto update here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, flask

I have a folder full of CSVs where new CSVs come in every 30 mins 
I have a flask.py script which checks the folder for all the CSVs, and reads all those CSVs, concatenate them and then use `df.to_html()` to show it over the webpage.

Now without restarting the `flask.py` script, is there a way to include the new CSVs? Something dynamic...

Comment: Rather than using the filesystem, have the CSVs be populated by POSTing them to an API endpoint on the flask service. Then your application knows when it needs to refresh the page. Alternatively, use a static site generator that gets triggered when a file in the application directory is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:-

```
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"

@app.route('/data')
def get_all_data():
    def generate():
       # do your work to put all csv's data into dataframe object 'df'
          while True:
              yield df.to_html()
              sleep(1800) # 1800 sec = 30 mins

    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```